# Settingwithcopywarning in python

Tags: python, time-series, warnings, recurrent-neural-network, forecasting

I am trying to forecast a time series data using RNN on python, I used this code: test['Predictions']=true_predictions, it gave a settingwithcopy warning, a value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a dataframe. I initially wanted to ignore it but the plot I got later made me understand that there is a problem. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/26R0z.jpg)

From the plot, the line for the predicted values should be similar to that of the original values, Xt, but they are totally different, the predicted values is like a straight line, it seems the code is picking one value as the predicted values instead of a series of different values. How do I correct this?

Edit: I have attached pictures of the codes, I'm sorry if this is not clear enough, it is my first time asking a question on this site and I'm still trying to understand how it works.
[Import relevant libraries and loading the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yepXs.jpg)

[Train and test the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGpXI.jpg)

[Define the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYD5J.jpg)

[Make predictions on the testing set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOAdf.jpg)

[Test predictions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bgXN.jpg)

[Predictions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rVox.jpg)

Comment: There are two predictions keys in your legend. Assuming you are referring to upper case `Predictions` (i.e. the green line).

Usually you can get rid of this error using something like `df.loc[:, 'Predictions'] = true_predictions` , but there may be more to it since we don't know what the data looks like.

What is the dtype and shape of `true_predictions`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.